# How to link a folder to oneDrive without moving the folder to the oneDrive folder in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I wanted to find out if it is possible to link my htdocs folder (which is not located in oneDrive) to oneDrive so that it will be synced without necessarily moving the folder to oneDrive. It will kind of like a copy mirroring the original htdocs folder. Changes made in the original folder will be updated in the second folder.

Comment: Requires setting your htdocs folder as your OneDrive account or setting up a symbolic link within your OneDrive directory to your htdocs folder

Comment: @Ramhound Oh kk. symbolic links,  I was looking for something like that.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following command to do so, linking `Pictures` to `new_folder`, and OneDrive will start to sync the contents of `Pictures`:

```bsh
Mklink /j "%UserProfile%\OneDrive\Documents\new_folder" "H:\Documents\Pictures"
```

Comment: This mind blowing! you can put any folders just using this simple command in CMD, I would add that for people that don't know where to do it.

Comment: This seems really neat but unfortunately I found that changes made in the original location are not synced up to the cloud until the OneDrive program is closed/re-opened (or pause then unpause syncing) so perhaps file system notifications are not received via the junction?

Comment: Works like a charm and changes are properly synchronized every time the automatic synchronization starts.

Comment: I wish this would work, but it doesn't (anymore). See also information from Microsoft about that:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/can-t-synchronize-onedrive-files-and-folders-from-a-local-file-location-other-than-the-default-onedrive-path-b7eef9d4-4203-431d-8345-fe49254f9da0#:~:text=You%20cannot%20use%20this%20workaround%20in%20reverse.%20The%20original%20or%C2%A0%3CTarget%3E%C2%A0folder%20must%20be%20located%20in%20the%20OneDrive%20directory

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have checked my solution to this issue yet, but I believe would worth your time, it is open source and free here:

https://github.com/ktheod/OneDriveBully

Essentially it is an app that provides you a nice GUI based symbolic link creation and periodically "bully"/trick OneDrive to scan and sync changes in all symlinked folders by renaming an empty file in the root folder of OneDrive.

Thanks,

Comment: You put a lot of effort into that app, however isn't it far more efficient and simple to use [`MkLink /J`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink)?

Answer (score 0):

Same solution using modern Windows command line:

Open "Windows PowerShell":

```
New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path "$env:OneDrive\Documents\new_folder" -Target "H:\Documents\Pictures"
```

Explanation: This creates a new folder link or junction point, as Microsoft calls it, within your OneDrive folder. This link is like a pointer so the content of "H:\Documents\Pictures" can also be accessed like if it exist in OneDrive\Documents\new_folder.

Comment: As also commented above: unfortunately this no longer works.

Answer (score -1):

Finally got this method to work, however a step seems to have been omitted (or unclear). The "%UserProfile%" refers to the "%CompletePath%" to the UserProfile uncluding "%C:\Users(UserProfile)%"

Comment: This is not an [answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer), but more of a [comment](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment) to @Zolbayer's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1518836/529800)